# Data migrations with Persistence(RDB, AOF)

Tags: redis

I had read Redis doc to find answer of title. But I can't find it.
I want to know how to operate of RDB and AOF when migrating of cluster nodes.

Assume there are 2 nodes in same cluster.(A node, B node)
* RDB, AOF option are on.

if A's some data is migrated to B, B operates AOF and Snapshotting as soon as getting the data?

If it is not, admin should explicitly send the command(appendonly, BGSAVE) to save changed dataset?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The persistence of each node will function as expected regardless of the origin of the data (user or migration). If RDB snapshots are configured, node B will perform a dump with the new data once the thresholds are reached. AOF will continue operating continuously on node B and any new data will be included in it.

Calling `BGSAVE` is always an option when you want to manually trigger a dump.